# How to securely deal cards?

Tags: encryption, zero-knowledge-proofs, protocol-design, randomness

Thanks to a certain pandemic going around I was wondering whether there is any cryptographic way to remotely deal cards without the dealer being able to know them and without requiring to trust a server for that. My first impulses involved [secret-sharing](/questions/tagged/secret-sharing) and [zero-knowledge-proofs](/questions/tagged/zero-knowledge-proofs) but that is probably not even related... Some first thoughts:

Given a stack $S$ of $N$ cards, $n$ shall be dealt to each hand $H_i, i\in\{1,2,...,p\}$ of $p$ players with the following requirements:

0. $N\ge n\cdot p$ (obviously)
1. Once a card has been drawn it cannot be drawn by someone else as well, i.e. $$\forall i\neq j: H_i\cap H_j = \{\}$$
2. No one must be able to determine which cards anyone else has nor which ones remain in the stack. Just passing around the encrypted state of a shuffle bag is thus not good enough. Maybe everyone should contribute some encrypted randomness which in a second round is used to determine the dealt cards?
3. At some point one must be able to proof a specific card is<sup>§</sup> currently in the hand.

Is there any method which can achieve this?

---

<sup>§</sup> I guess a blockchain could be used to keep track of the cards changing places later on

Comment: Maybe related to this question about Bingo: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/61680/2663 But here you cannot choose your board but get cards dealt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for ["mental poker"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mental_poker).

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mthPiiCS24A) is a video of Ron Rivest specifically discussing how to deal cards via mail/internet.

The paper [here](https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a066331.pdf) might also be a good read (from the creators of RSA).

Comment: Sounds perfect, thanks!